# In Pokemon Go, which moveset for Jellicent in PvP has the highest win rate result?

Tags: pokemon-go

Jellicent with:

Hex, Bubble Beam + Ice Beam

Hex, Bubble Beam + Shadow Ball

Hex, Shadow Ball + Ice Beam

Bubble, Bubble Beam + Ice Beam

Bubble, Bubble Beam + Shadow Ball

Bubble, Shadow Ball + Ice Beam

Comment: Could you at least say why its downvoted? This is not opinion based, I strictly said statistical win rate

Comment: My guess is that either there is not enough data for this (you could have searched this up yourself), or its impractical to answer it. (Look there are over like 200 pokemons in pokemon go, lets be serious, unless you're extremely devoted or have software capable of simulating battles, this is going to take awhile) It is also reliant on trainer skill as you can dodge attacks, etc.

Comment: Ok, if that was the case sure but people just downvote and dip? How is that good policy? I am pretty new to this site.

Comment: Its reasonable you're frustrated by downvoters who dip and don't give an explanation. The general reasons are, poor question (no its ok), off-topic (no), or impractical (yes somewhat). But they don't owe an explanation unfortunately, but the site does try and encourage people to give comments as how to improve questions. If your question happens to be closed, they must provide a reason.

Comment: That sucks. I wish you could see who downvoted, as to improve the site users. Thanks though

Comment: Downvotes are often seen as a negative thing; however they are intended to be constructive. There are close reasons, which are specific reasons as to why a question *will not* be answered, whereas downvotes are used to suggest that in its current form, it needs improvement, which is where comments can come in handy.

Comment: That said, welcome to Arqade, and thanks for taking the [Tour](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tour) and looking through the [Help Center](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help)!

Comment: Right thanks for that. All i received were downvotes, with no comments, so I have no idea why it was a bad question. It seems fine to me, but others may have diff opinions. If this question takes too much time too find, maybe there are other more time applicable people who can help

Answer (score 2):

I recommend [PvPoke](https://pvpoke.com/rankings/) for determining ideal movesets in PvP based on win rates. It ranks Pokemon against each other based on their match-ups against the rest of the metagame, with match-ups against more popular Pokemon being given higher priority. Each Pokemon is ranked based on its moveset that gives it the best overall match-ups. It gives different match-ups and ideal movesets for each league, including some special cups like Kanto Cup.

At the time of this post in each of these leagues, Jellicent's ideal movesets in the main leagues are:

- Great League: Bubble, Bubble Beam and Shadow Ball
- Ultra League: Hex, Shadow Ball and Ice Beam
- Premier Cup (Ultra without legendaries): Bubble, Bubble Beam and Shadow Ball
- Master League (normal and Classic): Hex, Shadow Ball and Ice Beam

Ranks and movesets can change over time. By default, these rankings assume that both players have 1 (and only 1) shield. This setting can be changed manually. Further details can be found [on their site](https://pvpoke.com/rankings/all/1500/overall/).

Answer (score 1):

**Jellicent move comparison vs. all Pokemon**

[Hex/BB/IB: 72%](https://pvpoke.com/battle/multi/1500/all/jellicent/11/1-1-2/2-1/)

[Hex/BB/SB: 75%](https://pvpoke.com/battle/multi/1500/all/jellicent/11/1-1-3/2-1/)

[Hex/IB/SB: 58.5%](https://pvpoke.com/battle/multi/1500/all/jellicent/11/1-2-3/2-1/)

[Bubble/BB/IB: 68.2%](https://pvpoke.com/battle/multi/1500/all/jellicent/11/0-1-2/2-1/)

[Bubble/BB/SB: 73.6%](https://pvpoke.com/battle/multi/1500/all/jellicent/11/0-1-3/2-1/)

[Bubble/IB/SB: 60.2%](https://pvpoke.com/battle/multi/1500/all/jellicent/11/0-2-3/2-1/)

Note that this is vs. all Pokemon in general. The ideal moveset for your Jellicent is going to depend on your team composition. It might be a good idea to run ice beam if your team is weak to dragon or ground types, despite Ice Beam typically having a lower win rate.